# Access Hardware Information from Web Browser

Tags: .net, silverlight, flash, browser, hardware

I am interested in creating a website that needs to know as much specific hardware (ie computer model, cpu model, RAM size, etc) as possible.

Are you aware of any method to find out this information?

I know about ActiveX controls, however I'd prefer to use a more flexible method.  Javascript?  Asp.NET?  Flash?  Java? Silverlight?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript : Impossible;

.Net/Silverlight (If you develop a non-based web browser app) : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/system-information-from-registry-in-silverlight-4/

Java (vi a java applet): [get OS-level system information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information).

ActionScript/Flash : I don't think you can get all the information you are looking for, but you can get the free available memory ([documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html)).

**EDIT :**
[Here is more information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) about the system information you can get through an applet.
For a RIA application, there are more functionnalities [listed here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/properties.html).
I found [a very good SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011063/how-many-hardware-details-can-a-java-applet-discover) that could be very useful.

To get the machine name, the easiest (only?) way to do so is to take it from the ip. So, a server language is needed here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can with AIR - its NativeProcess api.

Comment: You are right. Like Silverlight : If it run in a desktop mode, it's ok. But the question is about a browser script.

Comment: Ah - yes, you are correct. System.totalMemory is the OPs only option, then.

Comment: @Zakaria Do you know if the Java Applet method allows for more than just the number of cores and memory?  Something like the computer's model (ie "Dell Latitude E5500") or at least the CPU model?