# Can I get a computer's hardware information through WebAssembly code in the browser?

Tags: browser, webassembly

I am working on a Video Conferencing web application. I would like to reduce video quality on the computers which have older or less powerful hardware to manage their load. I know it is not possible to get exact hardware information from regular JavaScript running in the browser. But is it possible to get this from a C++ or Rust code that runs via WebAssembly?

Looking to get as much info as possible CPU/RAM/GPU

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Hardware Information from Web Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420636/access-hardware-information-from-web-browser)

Comment: Just play the video and check whether it drops frames.

Comment: @vahdet The question you have linked to was asked years ago and does not contain information about WebAssembly in particular.

Comment: @tkasul Thanks, I'll keep this in mind. Still curious about WebAssembly though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know it is not possible to get exact hardware information from regular JavaScript running in the browser. But is it possible to get this from a C++ or Rust code that runs via WebAssembly?

No.  WebAssembly has no access to any hardware information at all, except for what it can obtain via JavaScript.