# odoo 14 how to get the user hardware information for health monitoring

Tags: python, odoo

I need to get the internal user information hardware and software installed. Is this can be done with python through a browser then the user login or do I need to create a python app to send this information to odoo.

it is for IT help disk, so when the internal user creates a ticket I would have this info to help him/her.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not Odoo. The problem is a Browser cannot access to the hardware information.

[Access Hardware Information from Web Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420636/access-hardware-information-from-web-browser)

But you can write a script to execute on compute to send information in Odoo.

### Help:

You can use [Platform package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html) to get information from computer.

And use [Odoo External API](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/fr/developer/webservices/odoo.html) to inject data in Odoo.