# Login authentication using fingerprint

Tags: java, applet, biometrics

It's my final year project, which i'm making using java, and i have to develop one online attendance system for faculty and student. For faculty login, i need fingerprint login authentication, so i googled but i didn't find anything helpful in any case.

During my research, i found these sdk [neurotechnology](http://www.neurotechnology.com/fingerprint-biometrics.html), [grfinger](http://www.grfinger.com/applet/GrFingerAppletSample.html). But, i'm very confuse how to use these on my web application. My laptop already have one fingerprint hardware, which uses [authentec](http://www.authentec.com/) driver for windows login.

Please anyone help me to use my embed fingerprint reader for my web application. Thanks in advance !!

If there is any alternative for fingerprint login authentication (without using fingerprint reader hardware), in which we can just comparing the fingerprint manually, that can also useful for me. !!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you will need to use a signed Java applet for this. You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011063/how-many-hardware-details-can-a-java-applet-discover) previous SO thread in which something similar to what you want is being discussed.

That being said, you might also want to take a look at ["Why is your desktop app not a web app?"](http://java.dzone.com/why-desktop-not-webapp). In your case I think it should be the other way round but I think that it might outline some points which you might find useful.

That being said, you might want to opt for a desktop application which could have it's own web browser, such as [Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) so basically your Java application which is running on the client machine handles the authentication and then, it uses its built in web browser to do whatever it needs to be done.

EDIT:

I have never used biometric locks, so unfortunately I might not be able to provide much help on the topic. As I said earlier, a Signed Java applet should have access to your client devices. If you have limited knowledge, I would recommend you build some simple desktop applications so that you can get it to work. Once you do this, you can migrate everything to your applet. You can check out [this](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets.html) tutorial on how you can then include your applet into your web application. The tutorial uses Netbeans which in my opinion is a pretty good IDE.

I would recommend you look at some tutorials first to see the possible ways in which you can accomplish a given set of tasks. Once that you have found a way or two, you can then choose the best way which you can get them done.

Comment: what should i do..?? I mean, how can i use this into my web application. Because, i don't have much knowledge about fingerprint mechanism. So, if you will elaborate the each terms. i'll very much appreciate you !!

Comment: but, my question is not related to "how to embed applet on web". My question was, how can i use my embedded fingerprint reader into my web application. Is there any sdk/api available for free. Can i use my laptop fingerprint reader for login authentication.

Comment: @sql_query: Like I said, I can only tell you how I would go about it. With regards to the actual implementation, I cannot be of much help since I have never worked with such instruments and the actual implementation might depend on the actual model/brand. Since this is your final year project, it might be worth forking out some cash, it is in your benefit after all.

Comment: @sql_query: Then I would recommend that your either do some thorough searching or else change the field of your project.