# Bio metric device integration in java web application

Tags: javascript, jsp, web, biometrics

I am Integrating a bio metric finger print detection device with web based application where in  on click of a simple button we will start initializing device and start capturing the fingerprint details.
The code for initializing the device and capturing response is written in a Servlet because of which the web application is searching for the device on server machine but actually the device is connected to client machine(i.e. browser machine). so how to make jsp to access client machine device and capture response from it?(Preferably through javascript i guess).

Comment: Read this,nicely explained http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886411/how-to-capture-biometric-information-on-a-webpage-by-using-java

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a java applet here as the server side code will not be able to access it. Use a applet and access the device and finally send the data to the backend for other logics.

Comment: could you please elaborate how we should go on using applet any sample example or something of that sort.

Comment: Just searched in google and found http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/en-us/manual/fingerprint-sdk/using-the-sdk/fingerprint-sdk-java-for-windows-prerequisites/applet-prerequisites/applets-and-fingerprint

Comment: Also just got http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603556/login-authentication-using-fingerprint