# Get User Machine Information

Tags: database, reporting, scalability

Is there any way to detect what machine configuration end user has ?  Two main information I need is Processor , memory . I know web has limitations so this might be impossible .

Is there any activex plugin that can do this ? I see HP has a way to do this . It installs an activex plugin to do this http://h20239.www2.hp.com/techcenter/HP_SystemCheck/hp_syscheck.htm .

Comment: By what method are you extracting this machine information?

Comment: @njk I am not extracting any information . I am yet finding a way to do this .

Comment: But what are you trying to do with this information? I can just tell you to have the user open up their computer and check the parts.

Comment: I have a tool that they will be installing. Instead of they download and later find out that their machine is not having enough configuration I want to alert on page itself before they download .I know I can show them system requirement but in case they miss to read it.

Comment: Would a 3rd party app like [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) work? Or run > `dxdiag`?

Answer (score 1):

`Flash`, `Java` and `Silverlight` may help you to retrieve many system specific informations & configuration.

Below are the most possible way to perform `system level actions` on user's device via `Web Browser` and respective `plugin`.

- For Flash (Action Script 3): [System](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html%22zxc%22) and [Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html).
- Silverlight : [System Info. from Registery](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/system-information-from-registry-in-silverlight-4/)
- Java : [Possible information java applet can retrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011063/how-many-hardware-details-can-a-java-applet-discover)

Say thanks to `Zakaria` & have a look at same answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420636/access-hardware-information-from-web-browser).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Query:

```
USE [master];
GO
select 
    cpu_count,
    hyperthread_ratio,
    physical_memory_in_bytes / 1048576 as 'mem_MB',
    virtual_memory_in_bytes / 1048576 as 'virtual_mem_MB',
    max_workers_count,
    os_error_mode,
    os_priority_class
from 
    sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

Comment: this will not work in my case cause this wil give information of sql server and not end user .